# Sqllite update query in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm doing update method in my DB helper class. But I can't resolve where i've done a mistake. There is no errors in log, but my field in table doesn't update.

```
public void updateJSON(long id, String newString) {
    ContentValues dataToInsert = new ContentValues();
    dataToInsert.put("cityJSON", newString);
    String where = "id=?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
    this.db.update(TABLE_NAME, dataToInsert, where, whereArgs); 
}
```

I'm transferring json string (with commas, brackets etc) and ID of the field.

Comment: Are you sure that there's already a registry with this id in the table?

Comment: @FlávioFaria yes, I'm sure :)

Comment: Are you sure the column is called `id`? Normally on Android it's `_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
String[] whereArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
```

try

```
String[] whereArgs = { Long.valueOf(id).toString() };
```

that works for me.

Comment: @njzk2: `whereArgs` is a array of String. it gets initially populated with the String representation of the variable `id` (which is a long). note that i had to change the variable from a long to a String.

Comment: Yes, but i don't see how String.valueOf(long) is different from Long.toString(), mostly since the doc says : "`String valueOf(long l)` (...) The representation is exactly the one returned by the Long.toString method of one argument."

Comment: @njzk2: basically i looked at my code (that works) against their code (which doesn't) and posted the diff. i would now love to see both in the debugger and i think it would be obvious. or not. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try this code: `String mString = Long.toString(id);`

Answer (score 0):

`db.update(...)` method returns the number of rows affected. You can show this value in log.
If number of rows that was affected equals zero :

1. maybe there is something wrong with row names?
2. maybe `db` declared as `readableDatabase` instead of `writableDatabase`? i mean

`SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();`

instead of `getWritableDatabase()`?

EDITED:

You can write helper function just to be 100% sure that row (with id that you need) is actually exists in database:

```
public boolean isItemExistsInDB( int yourId){
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + 
                         TABLE_NAME+ " 
                         WHERE " + " id = '" + yourId+ "'";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    //count of rows with "id=yourId"
    int count= cursor.getCount();

    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "count="+count);

    if(count>0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
         //there is no item with "id=yourId"
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);
this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();

Comment: And yes, it returns zero rows. But there can't be mistake with row id. The mistake is somewhere about the query..

Answer (score 0):

I think use this code,

```
this.db.update(TABLE_NAME, dataToInsert, COLUMNNAME + "=?" ,
            new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
```